# R selecting rows and columns

Tags: r, subset

I'm new to R and I have 2 questions. So I have a dataframe that looks like this table:

| nr | c0 | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | **M** | Z |
| 2 | Z | U | C | **M** |
| 3 | N | K | N | D |
| 4 | **M** | L | Y | E |

First I would like to find all columns which contains the string *M* and store the column names in a new dataframe or a list:

| c_names |
| --- |
| c0 |
| c2 |
| c3 |

second I would like to select all rows containing the string *M*:

| nr | c0 | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | **M** | Z |
| 2 | Z | U | C | **M** |
| 4 | **M** | L | Y | E |

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For your first question

```
> data.frame(c_names = names(df)[colSums(df == "M") > 0])
  c_names
1      c0
2      c2
3      c3
```

- For your second question

```
> subset(df, rowSums(df == "M") > 0)
  nr c0 c1 c2 c3
1  1  A  B  M  Z
2  2  Z  U  C  M
4  4  M  L  Y  E
```

Comment: Thank you! This works graet but i have another problem i forgot to mention. In my dataframe there are also N/A entries. Do you have an idea how I can handle this?

Comment: @Horst-Jackson there is an option `na.rm = ` in both `colSums` and `rowSums`. Set it `TRUE`  when you want to remove `NA`s.

Comment: One last question. Is it also possible searching of a string which contains a M? e.g. changing first entry in c2 to xyM and the second entry in c3 to xyzM. The above result should be the same.

Comment: @Horst-Jackson Then you can use `grepl("M",s)`, where `s` the a string

Answer (score 3):

We can use `grepl` to search for match in strings, the output is logical.

```r
c_names <- colnames(df)[grepl("M", df)]
c_names
[1] "c0" "c2" "c3"
```

For the second question, we can use `rowSums` to find cells that equals "M", and turn that into a logical vector for indexing.

```r
df[as.logical(rowSums(df == "M")),]
  nr c0 c1 c2 c3
1  1  A  B  M  Z
2  2  Z  U  C  M
4  4  M  L  Y  E
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is combined `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-nr, ~case_when(. == "M" ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(c_names, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~ . == "M")) > 0)
```

```
nr c0 c1 c2 c3 c_names
1  1  A  B  M  Z      c2
2  2  Z  U  C  M      c3
3  4  M  L  Y  E      c0
```